# jQuery .ajax() async without freezing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm making an infinite scrolling page. Sometimes this code works perfectly, sometimes it loads page 13 first, when it should load page 1 first (page 0, the index, is already loaded) then page 2, 3, 4 etc when the user is 400px from the bottom of the page. Sometimes pages load twice at the same time, so it goes 1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6

I have async set to true, but would prefer it to be false. The issue with false is that freezes the page. To bypass this, I added the variable 'loadingMoreOpps'. loadingMoreOpps needs to be false before .ajax() is called, and is checked in the same conditional statement as the scroll position check.

```
    var loadingMoreOpps = false;
    var oppPagesLoaded = 1;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= ($(document).height() - 400)) && !loadingMoreOpps) {                     
            loadingMoreOpps = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: 'templates/opportunities/loadmore.php', 
                data: { page: oppPagesLoaded }, 
                beforeSend: function(response) {
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                async: true
                }).
                    done(function(response) {
                            $('#opp_container').append(response);
                            loadingMoreOpps = false;
                            oppPagesLoaded++;
                    }
                );
            }
    })");
```

Comment: You probably just need to debounce the `.scroll()` event so you process the last scroll event rather than the first one.  Also, now that you have `loadingMoreOpps` in there, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I thought that `loadingMoreOpps` would prevent `.ajax(` within the scroll event from calling more than once before the content is returned, but it seems like it isn't.

Comment: `loadingMoreOpps` should prevent multiple of these ajax calls at once.  I don't see an issue there.

Comment: Issue was oppPagesLoaded not resetting to 1 when I loaded the page again, due to my web application being heavily AJAX based.

To resolve this I simply added oppPagesLoaded = 1; without redeclaring the variable at the top of the relevant code block.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was `oppPagesLoaded` not resetting to 1 when I loaded the page again, due to my web application being heavily AJAX based.

To resolve this I simply added `oppPagesLoaded = 1;` without redeclaring the variable at the top of the relevant code block.